# Javascript auto update page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, auto-update

Can anybody give me a direction, I want to know how to do auto updating pages like facebook have for new status updates, new likes etc. Ie., if you have a status open in a window and a user click "like", the +1 like automatically appears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is really vague... As a general pointer, you could use a mediator pattern in javascript for publishing events and subscribing to them. Then, use ajax to get the new content and javascript again to update the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are done using a PUSH model (subscribe / publish).

The client side first subscribes by issuing an AJAX request. This AJAX request stays alive indefinitely. When the server receives a new like / comment, it publishes this update to the client side thereby ending the AJAX request. The client receives this update and isntantly issues another AJAX request.

It is broadly categorized as [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Once before, I had implemented a Comet web chat application and wrote a somewhat technical write up of what went into it. You can read it here, if interested.

**[Comet Web Chat Application](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150477920707912)**

Edit:

A heartbeat mechanism (PULL model) is definitely easier to implement, but a PUSH model is far more efficient.

Comment: For easy implementing, checkout SignalR in .net, or socket.io with just about everything else!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use ajax, which is a way to communicate with the database without reloading the web page : you could for example use the 
 **$ajax**
function of jQuery framework : [here's the doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

im not posting code, but here's a quick overview of what you might wanna do:

1. have the "like" image
2. create a script that binds a click handler to the image.
3. once clicked, the script sends an AJAX request to the server to increment the like
4. if that request succeeds, return data to the script indicating that it was a success. you might also want to return the number of likes and so on.
5. once the script knows the success, have it change your "like" image.

as for counting likes, well, its up to you. for a very broad question, this is a broad answer that will point you to the right path.