# Make a page refresh only in specific areas

Tags: jquery, mysql, reload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript auto update page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999112/javascript-auto-update-page)

Ok... So I am trying to build a messaging system with php and when a message comes in I need the little number >>>Messages (0)<<< to change to the new amount WITHOUT reloading the whole page.  It would be nice if I could just reload the entire page with jquery or something and then just the things that changed would change... Thats what I really want.

The number is coming from the amount of unread messages in the database relating to the loggedin user.  In the image you can see where the numbers show up when a new message comes in but not until the page is loaded... I need it to check for changes in at least 2 different locations and run querys about every 30 sec.
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need to use [ajax](http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/)

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999112/javascript-auto-update-page) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need **AJAX**, here is an example:

First, when you load the page, you need to get the last ID of the messages sent.

```
$lastID = SELECT MAX(id) AS `id` FROM `messages` WHERE `to` = . getLoggedUserId()
```

Then, you need to pass that to Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get("page.php?checkMessages&lastID=<?php echo $lastID; ?>", function(amount){
            if(amount > 0){
                $("span.newMessages").text(amount);
            }
        })
    },10*1000); // every 10 seconds
})
```

On *page.php*, you will have:

```
<?php
    if( isset($_GET["checkMessages"]) ){
        $lastID = (int)$_GET["lastID"]; // just for security
        $newMessages = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `amount` FROM `messages` WHERE `id` > ' . $lastID . ' AND `to` = ' . getLoggedUserId()
        echo $newMessages;
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Then, every 10 seconds, only the `span` with the amount of new messages will be loaded.